# Regex to match 1 or less occurrence of string?

Tags: regex

Suppose I want a regex to match "Jump over this bridge FOOL" as well as "Jump over this bridge". How do I make "FOOL" optional (0 or 1 occurrence)?

Comment: I don't understand why people downvoted this. Sure it's in a manual...but the simple fact is that API manuals generally SUCK, and stack exch. has become the go-to site for simple moderated answers a question without crappy API docs or fifteen-page blogs. I followed THIS link because I forgot how and needed a simple answer without spending half an hour reading thru a crappy manual just to find something simple.
The moderators here have to realize that StackExchange has become a PRODUCT that people RELY on. Questions like this are PRECISELY in the S.E. product definition. Live with it.

Comment: Agree. As @MarkGerolimatos did, I came here for a quick reference that was faster than wading through the regexp man page for the 9+ th time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[You might want to have a look at a regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Optional parts of a regex are indicated with a question mark:

```
Jump over this bridge( FOOL)?
```

In case you want to match *any* string that includes `FOOL` less than twice, things get a bit more complicated. Then you would be best off using the more advanced concept of a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!(.*FOOL){2})
```

This turns the logic on its head and asserts that the string *doesn't* contain 2 (or more) instances of `FOOL`.

Comment: -1, every single stack overflow question can be answered with "By reading a X tutorial", so that comment has no value other than to denigrate the poster, and should not be included. External links to answers are also frowned upon (the answer should be in the question itself, as you have done)

Comment: @pjcard agreed. I've reworded the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed it for a +1.

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `?` mark to specify the occurrence of a group as optional (occurs 0 or 1 time), or you can also use curly braces with min/max values as 0 and 1, so the answer is:

```
Jump over this bridge( FOOL)?
```

or

```
Jump over this bridge( FOOL){0,1}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this :

```
Jump over this bridge( FOOL)?
```

You can put a set of strings too :

```
Jump over this bridge( FOOL| FOOB)?
```